# Nativescript - Filterselect, RadListView. Which one do I use?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

First of all, I am new to Nativescript and I am also using Javascript. I am trying to add a control on my Nativescript application, where you can filter from a list and select the best option.

I have tried to use a RadListView with autocomplete, but no luck. I am not sure how to fill and use the Token from the sample.

As for the Filter select, I can't get the values to show in the control and I don't have a Javascript sample to compare.

So my question is: what do I use for my app? Is there another control that shows a list of labels and lets the user filter through it? Or where can I see some samples other than the docs site?

Thank you!

Comment: If you remove typings what's remaining in typescript code is all just JavaScript. If you are still not sure, use a TypeScript compiler where you can paste your code and see the JS equivalent. Both work great and which one to choose depends on your requirement / opinion. If you still have issues, consider posting sample code or possibly Playground sample.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out I needed to use the Filter select and the problem was that I wasn't binding the fields correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anybody that just wants a select in their Nativescript app and is not sure on how to do it:

I have chosen FilterSelect, as it had all I really needed. A dropdown with a filter.  The steps are as follows:

1. Add the plugin
2. Add the element on the xml page
   `xmlns:FS="nativescript-filter-select"`
3. Add the item on the page

```js
<FS:FilterSelect items="{{ items }}" searchHint="Search by name" hint="Choose" modal_title="Elements" search_param="srcparam" primary_key="indexparam" />
```

4. And set the array for the values, with the correct keys:

```js
  items.push({
          srcparam:elem.srcparam,
          indexparam:elem.indexparam
        });
```

Hope this helps.